# Loading an array using loadClass method

Tags: java

How can I load an array using loadClass method?

```
String className = "Customer[]";
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(className);
```

Comment: Maybe [Creating New Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arrayInstance.html) or [Java Reflection - Arrays](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/arrays.html)

Comment: Punter Vicky, are you trying to load an array using the `loadClass` method or load the array's class. If it's the latter, is there any reason you wouldn't use the `Class.forName()` method?

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer and Jonathan. I am trying to load an array with specific type.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You do not load the array class, just the class of the underlying type. The JVM will synthesize the array class when required.

Comment: Thanks EJP. Does it mean I can't use this method to load an array and should use java reflection to create a new array in order to dynamically create one?

Comment: You should use `new Customer[...]` if you can, otherwise `java.lang.reflect.Arrays`.